# How to read Excel File from AWS in Python 3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

the script below runs without any errors in python 2 but in python 3, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-11eb1acac6cc> in <module>
     16 response = s3client.get_object(Bucket='db_region_xyz' , Key='Aaa_bbb/Tester.xlsx')
     17 
---> 18 dataset = pd.read_excel(response['Body'])
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    302 
    303     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 304         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    305     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    306         raise ValueError(
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    819         self._io = stringify_path(io)
    820 
--> 821         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    822 
    823     def __fspath__(self):
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     19         err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
     20         import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
---> 21         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
     22 
     23     @property
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    348         elif hasattr(filepath_or_buffer, "read"):
    349             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
--> 350             filepath_or_buffer.seek(0)
    351             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    352         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str):
AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

What do I have to change in the below script that it will run in python version 3?

```
import boto3
from io import StringIO
from boto3 import session
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='region_xyz')
s3client = session.client('s3' , config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket='db_region_xyz' , Key='Aaa_bbb/Tester.xlsx')

dataset = pd.read_excel(response['Body'])
```

Regards

Comment: could you add few more lines from the stacktrace of the error maybe that will help to understand who is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()))
```